# Convert Java Date to Json Format

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, retrofit2

I am posting on the server a Java Date. 
I am getting this exception.

.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.Date` from String "Jan 1, 1970 2:00:00 AM": not a valid representation (error: Failed to parse Date value 'Jan 1, 1970 2:00:00 AM'

```
data class SyncTableBody<T>(val lastUpdatedDate: Date,
                            val inserted: List<T>,
                            val updated: List<T>,
                            val deleted: List<T>)
```

Comment: There is no JSON date format. There's only convention. *One* convention is to use a full ISO-8601 date/time string, e.g.: `"2019-09-06T11:03:56.752Z"`. Another convention is to use the milliseconds-since-the-Epoch value within a marker string like this: `"/Date(1567767921626)/"`. But in both cases, you have to set up your serlializer/deserializer to do that, AFAIK it's not automatic.

Comment: The newer java.time classes (like LocalDate) by default deliver that standard ISO date time format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added this date formatter to the retrofit call, and now I don't have this error anymore.

```
val gson = GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").create()
            val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("http://10.0.2.2:8080/")
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .build()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try specifying a `JsonFormat` in date like this:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;

data class SyncTableBody<T>(@JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss") val lastUpdatedDate: Date,
                            val inserted: List<T>,
                            val updated: List<T>,
                            val deleted: List<T>)
```